# How do you create Bag-of-Words feature vector after applying GloVe embedding?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis, libsvm, glove

If I have two movie reviews:

```
"this was a really good movie" and "i did not like this movie at all"
```

And I apply GloVe embedding to them I will get two vectors, with multiple word vectors inside them that look like this:

```
1st Review: [[300 Floats],[300 Floats],[300 Floats],[300 Floats],[300 Floats],[300 Floats]] 
2nd Review: [[300 Floats],[300 Floats],[300 Floats],[300 Floats],[300 Floats],[300 Floats],[300 Floats],[300 Floats]]
```

Basically each word in the review will be converted into a 300 element array of float point numbers. Since the arrays are of variable length I can't just plug them into a classifier.

I thought about doing some kind of Bag-of-Words representation, but I am not sure how I would implement that now that the words have become numbers.

Comment: Or you can try create vectors from whole review with SpaCy doc vectors https://spacy.io/api/doc#vector they should have the same length - 384 items each.

Answer (score 0):

The bag-of-words representation makes sense only when you work with words as discrete units. If you want to use SVM and no neural net, you can do with the embeddings is either mean-pooling or max-pooling (i.e., just the do the average or maximum over the sentence length).

In neural nets, the embeddings are processed either with a CNN or RNN which basically keep important information and throw away the rest. Since you don't have something likes in an SVM model, a reasonable thing to do would also be removing stopwords.

Comment: Could you please explain to my how I would use mean-pooling? Would I just sum together the individual word vectors and then divide by the length of the number of word vectors?

Comment: Yes, exactly, sum and divide by the length.

Comment: I am really surprised that you can just do that without losing the representation of the words in the sentence. There is no way for the classifier to know what the original words were.